# Grails acegi plugin remember me not working

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

Im am having problems with the remember me functionality of the grails acegi plugin (version 0.5.3)

The first time I login I check the remember me check box and login. This works. I then shutdown my browser and restart it and browse to the app. The login page is presented with the user name populated, password empty and remember me check box checked. I would have expect to navigate straight into the application (http://localhost:8080/application normally redirects to my landing page). If I try and manually login (enter password) it now doesnt work, I cant get past the login page.

Here is my login form:

```
<form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform'>
            <p>
                <label for='j_username'>Email</label>
                <input type='text' class='text_' name='j_username' id='j_username' value='${request.remoteUser}' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='j_password'>Password</label>
                <input type='password' class='text_' name='j_password' id='j_password' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='remember_me'>Remember me</label>
                <input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='_spring_security_remember_me' id='remember_me'
                <g:if test='${hasCookie}'>checked='checked'</g:if> />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type='submit' value='Login' />
            </p>
        </form>
```

SecurityConfig.groovy

```
    /** rememberMeServices */
cookieName = 'grails_remember_me'
alwaysRemember = false
tokenValiditySeconds = 1209600 //14 days
parameter = '_spring_security_remember_me'
rememberMeKey = 'grailsRocks'
```

This is just the default generated behavior. Am I missing something simple? Do I need to manually setup rememberMeServices or something?

I have confirmed that the "grails_remember_me" cookie is being created by using the chrome developer tools. I also get this same behavior with firefox.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: As this does not seem to be the complete SecurityConfig.groovy, I just want to check: do you redefine the property `providerNames` somewhere in the security config, thus perhaps inadvertently leaving out `rememberMeAuthenticationProvider`? That could cause the behavior you are getting. Otherwise, your config looks similar to ours and the remember me functionality works.

Comment: I havent redefined "providerNames". But if I look at the "DefaultSecurityConfig" of the installed plugin I dont see any mention of "providerNames". Should "providerNames" be defined somewhere in either the config for the plugin or application?

Comment: No, if you don't specify providerNames a default will be used and you should be OK. I was just speculating that maybe you have defined something of your own in there which could have caused your problem. It seems it must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never really got to the bottom of this. The way I "fixed" it was by upgrading to the new spring security plugin.

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core